# Bootstrap 3 horizontal dl: how to change dt width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using Bootstrap's horizontal definition lists, with a few changes.

My `dt` needs to be left aligned, and since I know the width of the content that goes there, I am reducing it from the default.  Here's the SCSS rules that I am applying:

```
dl.dl-horizontal {
  dt {
    width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  dd {
    margin-left: 135px;
  }
}
```

That works fine until I get to the small devices.  In these viewports I see that Bootstrap sets the left margin on the `dd` to 0.  Here's my attempt at that:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  dl.dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't take effect.

In the browser console I can see that the media query has been applied to the `dd`, but it has been overridden by the non-media-query rule.  As far as I can see, the specificity of both rules is identical, and I have tried locating the media query both above and below the non-media-query rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the !important tag into your SCSS code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  dl.dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!